# Installing a valid font errors out with "does not appear to be valid font"

Tags: installation, fonts

I have purchased and correctly installed a new font on one computer.  I then emailed that font in a zip file to be installed on another machine that runs Windows 7.

When I open the font and click the `install` button, I get the following error message:

> The file name "C:\Use...\charlottesanscom-book (2).ttf" does not appear to be a valid font

Does anyone have step-by-step instructions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Ensure that it works fine on one computer. What OS is the first computer? Try emailing it without putting it in zip file.

Comment: What happens if you rename "charlottesanscom-book (2).ttf" to "newfont.ttf"?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/957907/unable-to-install-fonts-on-windows-10/1093686

Answer (score 4):

Try to run it thru the free [Online Font Converter](http://onlinefontconverter.com) (developed [by me](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://warting.se/2010/03/15/ny-version-av-online-font-converter/)), it sometimes fixes broken fonts.

Comment: the archive gz that is downloaded using this link, is not getting extracted.

Comment: why not try zip?

Comment: This is down, but seemed like it was the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft Social's forum:

> I would suggest you to follow these
>   steps at the time of installing and
>   check if the issue is resolved.
>
> • If you install a TrueType font with
>   exactly the same name as a PostScript
>   font on the same computer, Windows
>   won't know which one to access, which
>   could result in a font type being
>   altered. To avoid this, don't install
>   different types of fonts with the same
>   name.
>
> • If a program is open when you
>   install a font, the program might not
>   register the font. Try closing and
>   then reopening the program.
>
> • Some fonts require that you install
>   two files in the same folder: A bitmap
>   file for the on-screen font and an
>   outline file for the printer. If a
>   bitmap file and an outline file are
>   available for a particular font, make
>   sure you install both files.
>
> [For further information, visit this
>   link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Fonts-frequently-asked-questions)
>
> I would also suggest you to right
>   click on the setup file of the program
>   and choose Run as Administrator to
>   install and check if the issue is
>   resolved.
>
> [You may also refer the below
>   mentioned link.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Install-or-delete-fonts)
>
> If this does not help then, I would
>   suggest you to copy the capture it.ttf
>   files and paste them to fonts folder
>   and check if the issue is resolved.

---

Some side-notes:

**You probably first have to unzip the font, else you can't properly install it.**

If it doesn't work then, try following these steps.

### To add a new font

*Note To reinstall standard Windows fonts, go to the "To reinstall the standard fonts included with Windows" section.*

**To install a font, follow these steps:**

- Click Start, and then click Run.
- Type the following command, and then click OK:
  %windir%\fonts
- On the File menu, click Install New Font.
- In the Drives box, click the drive that contains the font that you want to add.
- Note The floppy disk drive is typically drive A or drive B. The CD drive is typically drive D.
- In the Folders box, click the folder that contains the font that you want to add, and then click OK.
- In the List of fonts box, click the font that you want to add. To select more than one font at a time, press and hold the CTRL key while you select each font.
- Click to select the Copy Fonts To Fonts Folder check box. The new font is saved in the Windows\Fonts folder.
- Click OK.

[From the Microsoft knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;314960&x=12&y=14)

If all else fails, you'll have to download the font again to ensure you have a proper/uncorrupted version.