# I cannot install truetype fonts in windows 10. I can't even get the option to do so

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I do have my windows firewall turned on. When I open the control panel fonts, file, there is no option to install new fonts. Any suggestions? This is really frustrating.

Comment: Do you have Windows Firewall enabled or disabled.  Your first sentence does not make that clear.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/957907/unable-to-install-fonts-on-windows-10?rq=1).  You will have to do a better job indicating the reason this shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you already downloaded the fonts you wish to install? If you have, right click on the font file (if you have file extensions enabled, the font will end with a .ttf file extension) and then click on Install to install the font.

If you have many fonts, you can select them all using Ctrl-A and then right click and select Install.

Answer (score 0):

This should help with **some** fonts you used to be able to use. Right-click the font you're trying to re-install. If 'properties' is an option, click that. Look at the very bottom of the box, where there are tick boxes like 'read only'. There may be another one warning the font has been blocked. Tick 'unblock' and see if you can access the font after that.

Sadly, a lot of decorative fonts I used to use for programs and posters (all volunteer stuff, no commercial use) don't have 'unblock' as an option, so I'd be grateful for any suggestions as to where I can find them in a form Windows 10 and Word will use, or can be induced to use.