# Apple Color Emoji still not a valid font on Windows 10 1703?

Tags: windows, fonts

Is it possible to install the Apple Color Emoji on Windows 10? I mean even not be default emoji font of Windows 10. I mean even be just be installed so I can use it as glyph icon font on my design tools. The TTC file extracted from Mac looks like it doesn't work. The [answer from this other thread](https://superuser.com/a/1062437/739227) says it now Windows 10 as of 1703 supports all OpenType SVG encoding, but it's still not installable even if I'm already in 1703? Is it possible to just convert it to other font file type together intact with it's graphic color glyphs? Mess with some metadata on FontForge (tho Font Forge looks doesn't support yet this encoding too, wouldn't show the emoji artwork) Does it have DRM or license that's why this isn't working?

I also want to also install Google's Noto Color Emoji too but it wouldn't install either

Comment: Which version/build of Windows 10 are you using? [You need at least 1703](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/06/using-color-fonts-beautiful-text-icons/) for Apple emoji support. ([See also.](https://superuser.com/a/1062437/1686))

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help, I'm already in 1703 and it still can't be installed, it says not a valid font? Anything? Is the Apple Color Emoji font protected by some sort of license or DRM or something, do I need to tweak some metadata on FontForge to make it work in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's out yet, if not will not be out. I tried downloading the font on 1703 and it doesn't work for me either.
It could just be an iPhone font.
But, a good alternative is to look up the emoji as a transparent png. This is probably gonna be the most convenient way for awhile.