# Replace Windows 11 Emoji Font

Tags: fonts, windows-11, emoji, emoji-keyboard

I really don't like the new Windows 11 redesigned emoji font (for various aesthetic reasons, and it's lack of country flags). Is there a way to completely override it with another font (say, the old Windows 10 Emojis, or some Linux/Apple emoji font)?

I know people have done similar things on Windows 10 (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1062418/how-do-i-replace-windows-10s-emoji)), but I can't tell with Windows 11.

My goal is to have the old font completely gone (or at least not the default any longer) and a new font in its place.

Comment: You might have luck with the OpenMoji font.

Comment: [Twemoji](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/twemoji) would also work and it would fix emoji flags issue, but how to set it as default emoji font?

Comment: Based on everything I know that has changed with Windows 11, I see no reason to believe, that the answers to that existing question do not apply to Windows 11.

Answer (score 5):

1. Press the keys <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. In the panel displayed, type regedit
3. Click yes to make changes
4. Under the File button (next to view, edit, favorites, etc.) in the
   top right, type `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
5. Scroll down until you find **Segoe UI Emoji**, and delete it.
6. Install [**the attached file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vEd37pjSiyAVWxr7MBLMQk63MhSnNGji/view?usp=sharing) or go to the techpowerup post. (Right-click the attached file > More
   options > Install for all users.)
   It is the latest windows 10 emoji set.
7. Restart your pc
8. You just installed the windows 10 emojis.

It may not include the flags or the "newly invented" emojis, but it is the Windows 10 emoji font.

See also [**this post**](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/change-windows-11-emoji-set.291051/#post-4685906#:%7E:text=note:%20%22new%20invented%22%20emojis%20are%20not%20included) from techpowerup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Windows compatible Unicode 15.0 Noto-Color-Emoji TTF
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/main/fonts/NotoColorEmoji_WindowsCompatible.ttf

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment.