# Can't install new fonts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I am using Windows 10. Every time I try to install a font I get the below message.

> The file  does not appear to be a valid font

- I have gotten files from many different sites.
- I have tried both .ttf and .otf fonts.
- I have checked my firewall. It is on. My machine won’t let me turn it off anyway.
- I have given myself administrator permissions.
- I have changed the file ownership on the file.
- I have tried a scan of the machine.
- I have tried several file converters.
- I have tried making a copy of the file and installing the copy.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: *You need administrator privilege and (probably) install this font for all users -- at least this is the only way that I found working on my side.*

---

Double-clicking on a .ttf file ends with:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wDJYFGG.png]

Right-clicking on .ttf file and selecting *Install* ends with:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/c3Mavju.png]

Right-clicking on .ttf file and selecting *Install for all users*:

[image]

does the magic!